# Custom protoc plugin parsing not working for custom options

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am trying to write a protoc plugin that requires me to use custom options. I defined my custom option as shown in the example (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#customoptions):

```
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

extend google.protobuf.MessageOptions {
    string my_option = 51234;
}
```

I use it as follows:

```
message Hello {
    bool greeting = 1;
    string name = 2;
    int32 number = 3;

    option (my_option) = "telephone";
}
```

However, when I read the parsed request, the options field is empty for the "Hello" message.

I am doing the following to read

```
data = sys.stdin.read()

request = plugin.CodeGeneratorRequest()
request.ParseFromString(data)
```

When I print "request," it just gives me this

```
message_type {
  name: "Hello"
  field {
    name: "greeting"
    number: 1
    label: LABEL_REQUIRED
    type: TYPE_BOOL
    json_name: "greeting"
  }
  field {
    name: "name"
    number: 2
    label: LABEL_REQUIRED
    type: TYPE_STRING
    json_name: "name"
  }
  field {
    name: "number"
    number: 3
    label: LABEL_OPTIONAL
    type: TYPE_INT32
    json_name: "number"
  }
  options {
  }
}
```

As seen, the options field is empty even though I defined options in my .proto file. Is my syntax incorrect for defining custom options? Or could it be a problem with my version of protoc?

Comment: The data is *extensions* to the options object. Have you used the extension API? You must use an extensions API to read custom options. To see if it is there you could use descriptor-set-output and upload the file to https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode - it pulls any file apart to show all fields

Comment: Thanks for the response, @MarcGravell! I've been messing with the extensions API but can't get it to list out the extensions that have been made to the options. This is what I have so far. Could you help me access the elements within that object?

 `d = msg.DESCRIPTOR.GetOptions().Extensions` where msg is a message within my proto file

Comment: Well: what language / framework are you using? The syntax for accessing extensions depends on that. There are examples for C++ here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#extensions

Comment: I'm using python, but the example in the link you provided doesn't seem to work. Trying to access `my_proto_file_pb2.my_option` gives me an error saying `AttributeError: 'FileDescriptorProto' object has no attribute 'my_option'`. Do I need to be using the protoc generated files to access the extensions? @MarcGravell

Comment: that would depend on the framework you're using; I can't advise on python, sadly

Answer (score 5):

I'm making my protobuf python plugin.
I also got the problem like yours and i have found a solution for that.

- Put your custom options to a file my_custom.proto
- Use protoc to gen a python file from my_custom.proto => my_custom_pb2.py
- In your python plugin code, import my_custom_pb2.py `import my_custom_pb2`

Answer (score 4):

Turns out you need to have the _pb2.py file imported for the .proto file in which the custom option is defined. For example, it you are parsing a file (using `ParseFromString`) called `example.proto` which uses a custom option defined in `option.proto`, you must import `option_pb2.py` in the Python file that calls `ParseFromString`.

Comment: Just to add that you can access a property of the extension with
`if field.options and field.options.HasExtension(myextensionpkg.msgtype): return field.options.Extensions[myextensionpkg.msgtype].some_property`